# You can see me but you see through me

Tags: riddle, word, physics

This is my second (easy) riddle:

You can see me but you see through me.

I can fill the room but I will vanish as soon as nobody creates me.

I transport energy but I am not sure if I am made of physical matter.

Nobody is faster than me but I cannot drive on regular streets.

I do not need anything to survive but there are things that can stop me.

I am information but I can overwrite myself.

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight-forward answer:

> Light

You can see me but you see through me.

> We can see through he medium light passes through and see the light reflected off objects.

I can fill the room but I will vanish as soon as nobody creates me.

> A brightly lit room can get dark as soon as the light source is cut off.

I transport energy but I am not sure if I am made of physical matter.

> The basic composition of light, photons, is not tangible matter but transport energy.

Nobody is faster than me but I cannot drive on regular streets.

> Nothing beats speed of light but as it’s not a vehicle in itself.

I do not need anything to survive but there are things that can stop me.

> Light can be obstructed by an object

I am information but I can overwrite myself.

> Light can be used to pass information but it can be disrupted through interference.

Comment: 3 is not exactly what I thought about but it is valid too.